# ADF fail pipeline if Until inner activity fails

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to force a failure of the entire pipeline if an inner activity in the Until fails.

[image]

The Until has these activities. If the Stored Proc fails the Until will continue to loop.

Is there a way to fail the entire pipeline? Thanks

[image]

Update:

I tried the failure task but the Until continues to run:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added fail task in the Until and amended the expression to:

```
@or(greater(variables('RunDate') ,utcnow()), activity('Fail').output)
```

Looks to be working as expected now

Answer (score 0):

On the Stored Procedure activity, click the "Add output" option and select "Failure":
[image]

Add a Fail activity and connect it to the Failure path:
[image]

In the Fail activity, under Settings, configure the message and code:
[image]

This should fail the entire pipeline.

Comment: Hi. I tried that previously but the Until continued to run. I've added some screenshots to the original post

Comment: What is the expression for your Until? Can you set a value that will cause it to complete?

Comment: @greater(variables('RunDate') ,utcnow()) - it could be that which is causing to loop continuously. Any suggestions on how that can be improved?

Comment: What is the value of RunDate? Is it ever reset? If the variable never changes, seems it would create an endless loop.

Comment: Hi. RunDate would have 2 weeks added to it following the success of the preceding tasks. I think the issue was if the preceding tasks failed then RunDate would never be set. I've amended the expression as so: @or(greater(variables('RunDate') ,utcnow()), activity('Fail').output). Looks to be working :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable called Failure Flag with below logic:

@greaterOrEquals(length(activity('Z').error?.message), 1)

So in case if there is any failure, the above variable would be true. And you can use this variable to break out of loop